# .Net 5 Azure Function not showing in Portal

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions

I recently upgraded my Azure Function app to .Net 5 in isolated mode. I have this running fine locally in VS Code and am able to debug one of my http trigger functions. I am using Azure DevOps pipelines to deploy this to Azure. The deployment is successful, but I am unable to view my functions in the Azure portal.

[image: Screenshot of Azure Portal]

I am able to see all the deployment files when I console into the function app and I see that the functions.metadata file exists. However, logs screenshot below shows it cannot find any functions metadata?

[image: FunctionApp Logs]

Any ideas what to try next? The Azure Function app is running on Windows.

Thanks,
Param

Comment: In which deployment method we are following to deploy the functions app, I understand that from Azure Pipelines you've deployed to function app, need some clarity on how you've pulled the code to Azure DevOps pipelines. 
Add more information to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I finally was able to get this to work by creating a brand new function app in consumption mode. The previous function app was using a shared App Service plan. Weird.